# Calling action function wit api in python

Tags: python, bots, wit.ai, wit-ai

I want to get the stock price of any item. I have a function `getPrice` which returns the price of the item. I am trying to use `wit ai`. 
This is what I have tried.

```
from wit import Wit

def getPrice(request):
    #statements
    return price


def send(request, response):
    print request['text']
    print('Sending to user...', response['text'])

actions = {
    'send': send,
    'getPrice':getPrice
}

client = Wit(access_token="<token>", actions=actions)

resp = client.message('what is the stock price of xyz')
print('Result: ' + str(resp))
```

and the result I am getting is:

```
Result: {
u 'entities': {
    u 'search_query': [{
        u 'suggested': True,
        u 'confidence': 0.578445451443443,
        u 'type': u 'value',
        u 'value': u 'stock of xyz'
    }],
    u 'item': [{
        u 'confidence': 0.9613219630126943,
        u 'value': u 'xyz'
    }]
},
u 'msg_id': u '5ac1a450-7c5d-3190-8666-5d88a1884f94',
u '_text': u 'what is the stock of xyz?'
}
```

I want the Bot to display the price. How can I call this action function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
print resp['entities']['item'][0]['value']
```

Comment: It's giving `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: also, `xyz` is not the result. It's the one whose stock I am trying to get.

Comment: Error is fixed, but it's not returning the price. It's showing the` item name` whose stock I am trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
print('Result: ' + str(resp))
```

try:

```
stock = resp['entities']['item'][0]['value']
print('Price: {}'.format(getPrice(stock)))
```